# Left align buttons and FAB on top of BottomNavigationBar

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design, bottomnavigationview, floating-action-button

I'm looking at the Material Design specification and see this bottom toolbar which looks good with the so-called End-Fab. https://material.io/design/components/app-bars-bottom.html#anatomy

I currently have a standard BottomNavigationBar with a Fab above, but I would very much like to left align the icons and move the fab down over the bar, as in the images in the link above.

Is it possible to do this and still keep the BottomNavigationBar or should I switch to the Bottom app bar (and rewrite the navigation logic)?

Update:

My question is not about how to align the fab, but rather how to incorporate it the same way as with the Bottom toolbar as in the images in the link above.

Comment: what kind of layout are you using? `RelativeLayout`? `ConstraintLayout`? `CoordinatorLayout`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bottom Align Floating Action Button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30769080/bottom-align-floating-action-button)

Comment: @Polar I'm using a `CoordinatorLayout`.

Comment: No, it is not a dublicate of linked post. The fab is already at `bottom|end`, but I want it to be a part of the bottom navigation bar as with the bottom toolbar as shown in the link in the question. @Polar

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add an overlapping button in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43456856/how-to-add-an-overlapping-button-in-android)

Comment: So based on the links you guys sent, I should create it myself and not use neither of the BottomNavigationBar or BottomToolbar?